# Isolate networks whilst sharing NAS

Tags: routing, switch

[image]

- All devices on the network use CAT6 Ethernet cable.
- Router has DHCP enabled.

I want to seperate the above network to incoporate another network which it's main use is for IP cameras (not implemented yet). Both networks need to access the NAS as a 'shared resource', but both networks should not be able to talk to one another.

How can I isolate both networks from each other whilst sharing a resource which is important to both?

Comment: it depends of which device you will add for the new network. An unmanaged switch can't do what you want. Could be done with a managed (vlan capable) switch, depending of the model, and a router. Keep in mind that both product recommendation and home networking are off-topic here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Configure VLAN "cameras" on the switch along with a unique subnet for them to use, say, 10.2.2.x/24.  On the router, if you have a spare ethernet port, assign it ip address 10.2.2.254/24.  If no spare ethernet interface, reconfigure link to switch as a trunk so it gets frames from both VLAN's (default and cameras).</del>

<del>In any case, simply create an access list so that the only device that the cameras VLAN/subnet can access is the IP address of the NAS.</del>

purchase a decent switch (one that supports VLANs and PoE+ for your cameras).

Answer (score 0):

If You "like" cheap unmanaged switches, You can use separate unmanaged switches for users and cameras. And connect NAS and switches to different ports of router.

But unmanaged switches for untrusted users can be bad idea anyway.

Look at cheap more or less managed switches like [Mikrotik](http://routerboard.com/products/group/18) or [Ubiquiti](https://www.ubnt.com/edgemax/edgeswitch/) if You need PoE.

Without managed switch or using separate unmanaged switch per isolation group 
only fake isolation posible. By assign multiple subnets on single router port. And only in one dynamic DHCP possible.

It can depend on router features. What is Your router?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to connect NAS to the router instead of switch and camera also(if you have only one camera). 3 different networks would do.